# Fitting $ e^{-\alpha \left ( \Delta d \right )+\beta}+c$ to data set

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have a set of data points

```
d = {{0.0461538, 0.7}, {0.0576923, 0.5}, {0.0692307, 0.3}, {0.0807692, 0.25}, {0.0923076, 0.2}}
```

The curve I am attempting to fit onto this data set is the expression

> $$e^{-\alpha \left ( \ d \right )+\beta}+c$$

Mathematica is not returning anything sensible which must indicate I am doing something wrong.
What I get is:

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Kuba OP has been updated. $c, \alpha, \beta$ are constant.

Comment: `model = c + Exp[-a x + b]; fit = FindFit[d, model, {a, b, c}, x]`

Comment: `Assumptions` is an `Option` not a function.

Comment: `Assumptions` is typically not supported by functions unless the docs specifically say it is.  Its a good habit to read through all the docs, opening the options tab and so on to look for examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you think you need to need use `Assumptions` as it doesn't appear to be necessary for your data and curve form combination.  Here is one way to provide the fit:

```
data = {{0.0461538, 0.7}, {0.0576923, 0.5}, {0.0692307, 
   0.3}, {0.0807692, 0.25}, {0.0923076, 0.2}}
model = c + Exp[-α d + β]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {α, β, c}, d];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {α->43.50629849296479`,β->1.4851929663566672`, c->0.11398654360353833`} *)
Show[ListPlot[data],
  Plot[nlm[d], {d, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

But especially because you only have 5 data points and are estimating 4 parameters (α, β, c, and the error variance), the quality of the fit based on looking at the above figure is going to be misleading at best.

To get a better "visual feel" for the quality of the fit, you should (always) consider plotting confidence and prediction bands (depending on how you expect to use the resulting fit):

```
Show[ListPlot[data],
 Plot[{nlm[d], nlm["SinglePredictionBands"], 
   nlm["MeanPredictionBands"]}, {d, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, {"Predicted", "95% Prediction Band", 
     "95% Confidence Band"}]]]
```

[image: Data with prediction and confidence bands]